# Вызов lru_cache из functools

Tags: python, python-3.x

Известно, что в Python синтаксис:

```
@decorator
def function():
    return ...
```

аналогичен:

```
def function():
        return ...
function = decorator(function)
```

Но когда я попробовал реализовать подобное поведение с `lru_cache` из `functools`, он не сработал. Посмотрев повнимательнее, я увидел, что в сигнатуре вообще нет функции, которая принимается.

Теперь прошу объяснения, а каким образом мне вызвать `lru_cache` без использования спец. синтаксиса @ в Python?

Comment: Что значит «он не сработал»? Как вы это проверяли?

Comment: Ну взял и запустил код...

Comment: Что значит не сработал? Не было мемоизации. Вы можете сами любую функцию придумать и проверить.

Comment: Как вы проверили, что «не было мемоизации»?

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов А почему вы не хотите как декоратор использовать? Там потом можно статистику попадания в кэш посмотреть и понять использовался кэш или нет.

Comment: Декоратор хочу и использую через @, но меня просто смутило данное поведение когда я объяснял человеку как обычно декораторы работают наткнулся на этот момент и стало интересно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну в общем-то понятно, почему у вас "не работает", хотя другие ответы на ваш вопрос тоже правильные.

```
def fib(n):     
    return 1 if n == 0 or n == 1 else fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

Если вы обернёте функцию `fib` в декоратор, то имя `fib` получит кэшированная версия функции, поэтому кэшироваться будет как основной вызов функции `fib`, так и рекурсивные вызовы `fib` из самой себя.

А вот в случае, если вы вручную обернёте функцию `fib` в `lru_cache` и вызовете эту обёртку, то исходная функция `fib` так и останется обычной, не кэшированной. И все рекурсивные вызовы будут к обычной версии `fib`, от такого кэширования толку не будет, конечно.

```
cached_fib = lru_cache()(fib)
cached_fib(30)
print(cached_fib.cache_info())
```

Кэшированная функция вызвалась только один раз:

```
CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=1, maxsize=128, currsize=1)
```

Но! Это же питон. Вы можете присвоить кэшированную версию обратно в название исходной функции и всё будет кэшироваться:

```
fib = lru_cache()(fib)
fib(30)
print(fib.cache_info())
```

Кэш работает, потому что `fib` теперь кэшированная:

```
CacheInfo(hits=28, misses=31, maxsize=128, currsize=31)
```

Итак, по идее ваш код изначально должен был сработать с кэшированием, просто вы не нашли правильную форму вызова декоратора вручную.

Comment: Отличный ответ - все прекрасно расписано)

Answer (score 4):

Пример:

```
In [496]: def f(i):
     ...:     return i**2
     ...: 

In [497]: lru_cache()(f)(3)
Out[497]: 9

In [498]: lru_cache()(f)(4)
Out[498]: 16
```

**Пояснение:**

`lru_cache` возвращает функцию декоратор, которая ожидает на вход вашу функцию, которой в свою очередь нужно передать аргументы.

Comment: Я вызывал как `lru_cache(f)`

Comment: Хм, я попробовал проделать это же с функцией: 
`def fib(n):
    return 1 if n == 0 or n == 1 else fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)`
не сработало

Comment: Я имею в виду, я вызываю `lru_cache()(fib)(50)` и оно не работает :), может у меня совсем все плохо с головой, конечно....

Comment: я не уверен, что при таком вызове `lru_cache` сможет реально кэшировать результаты - это надо копаться и проверять...

Comment: А в чем смысл тогда такой записи, если она не кэширует как при вызове обычного декоратора?)

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов Ну это вы уже получается хотите свой код в чужую функцию что ли заинжектить, в чём смысл этого всего?

Answer (score 3):

Нет ни каких проблем, не понимаю, почему для вас «не сработало», на мой комментарий вы не ответили:

```
from functools import lru_cache

def f(x):
    return x * x

f = lru_cache(f)          # вместо @

for i in (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2):
    f(i)

print(f.cache_info())
```

Вывод:

> ```
> CacheInfo(hits=4, misses=2, maxsize=128, currsize=2)
> ```

Comment: какая у вас версия Python? Я получаю `TypeError: Expected maxsize to be an integer or None` при вызове `f = lru_cache(f)`

Comment: подозреваю что нормальной мемоизации для рекурсивных функций у вас таким способом получить не получится - попробуйте получить ряд фибоначчи и сравните cache_info у этого способа и если применить декоратор...

Comment: @MaxU: 3.8.3. В документации написано: «Changed in version 3.8: Added the user_function option».

Comment: @MaxU, *«подозреваю что нормальной мемоизации для рекурсивных функций у вас таким способом получить не получится»* - ну, получилос: `CacheInfo(hits=996, misses=500, maxsize=128, currsize=128)` для рекурсивным способом вычисленных первых 500 чисел.

Comment: @MarianD Покажите код )  Так не должно было закэшироваться )

Comment: Аааа, дошло до меня тоже )

Comment: @CrazyElf: `def fib(n):
    if n < 2: return n;   return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)`

Comment: @MarianD Да я понял уже, надо было просто обратно присвоить в название функции кэшированную и тогда работает.